Merge fonts of multiple texlive installations
I have to install multiple texlive (with different versions) on my Ubuntu server, and I'm wondering if I can merge the font files for the multiple installations.
Because the font files take up most of the disk space, most of the fonts are duplicated.
For example, can I simply move all the content from /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts and /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts to /usr/share/fonts/, and then run fc-cache -fsv?
